# SEOmatic page parent?

Tags: plugin-seomatic

I was wondering if it is possible to create a SEO Title Source in SEOmatic where the page title is output and then the parent/section page title e.g.:

{entry.title} | {{ entry.parent.title }} | Company Name

(The entry.title works but am not sure if its possible to get a parents page title)

Thanks
Malcolm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you should definitely be able to do what you want.

What I do is I test the code in the actual Twig template used to display the page, and then once I have it working, I paste it into the SEOmatic field, and add `object.` in front of the `entry`.

e.g.: If this gives you the results you want in the template:

```
{{ entry.title }} | {{ entry.parent.title }} | Company Name
```

Then when you paste it into SEOmatic's CP fields, it'd look like this:

```
{{ object.entry.title }} | {{ object.entry.parent.title }} | Company Name
```

I find that this makes it easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks Andrew thats really great answer and helps a lot